# pg_dump behaviour with -B option

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Recently we had to dump and restore our postgres db from one cloud provider to another one. We have used pg_dump for that and below is the command.

```
pg_dump -F t -h HOST -U USER -d DB -f C:\Users\Shariq\Downloads\Prod-DB\noblobswithschema.tar -Z0 -v -B
```

It took hardly 10 minutes to generate the dump file and we were able to import it using pg_restore without any issues. As per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) -B option is used to exclude large objects from the dump.

Below I am adding more details,

1. DB size is 128 GB (based on `pg_database_size`) but overall table size are around 2 GB. And 2 GB is valid based on information we have in database. We ran VACUUM standard command which didn't make any difference to database size. We didn't run VACUUM FULL though.
2. There is no `bytea` column in whole database which can be called large objects. There are some `text` columns which I was thinking can be also included as large objects but I am not sure.

Now the question is without `-B` flag in `pg_dump` it was taking forever to dump the database and also dump size was getting upto 300 GB. I have tried different flags such as `-j` for directory based backup, which was also taking forever. As we didn't have any column with datatype `bytea` we used `-B` option assuming other `text` datatype are not considered as large objects. Our restore has all the data including `text` columns. I am not sure why the `pg_dump` was taking forever without `-B` flag. If someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: 1) `bytea` != large objects.  2) See [Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html) for what are. 3) Query [pg_largeobject](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-largeobject.html) to see if any are in the source database.

Comment: Ok thank you for the information, I dont think we have created any large objects so why without -B pg_dump taking a lot of time

Comment: I'm betting you did. To know rather then think, query `pg_largeobject` table in source database.

Comment: ok will check that once.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `bytea` after all, you are using large objects. That is a bad idea, as you are discovering. If you have enough large objects, you won't be able to dump or upgrade the database any more, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/12601596dbbc4c01b86b4ac4d2bd4d48%40EX13D05UWC001.ant.amazon.com) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/a9f9376f1c3343a6bb319dce294e20ac%40EX13D05UWC001.ant.amazon.com).
There is no known remedy for that. Get rid of large objetcs!