# How do I extract/seed Large Objects into a Postgres Database using a Migration?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

How do I extract/seed Large Objects into a Postgres Database using a Migration?

Inside my Postgres database, I have a set of large objects including one that is a json file. The information kept inside the json file has been determined to be desirable to be extracted into our database as a set of tables instead of JSON.

In order to maintain backwards compatibility, I want to run this as a part of our migration bundle created using dotnet entity framework as that is our main tool for maintaining our database. This is to maintain a singular script that controls upgrades and makes it easy to deploy.

In dotnet entity framework, all migrations seem to be purely SQL, but I need to load the data into memory, so that I can use it to seed the new tables.

How can I accomplish the extraction of the large objects so that I can use it to seed the newly created tables as a part of a migration?

I have asked AI this question, but got non-answers.

I have investigated the dotnet ef migrations builder and tried to figure out if it could have a custom operation that directly talked to the database model only to find it only operates with sql.

I have considered that perhaps making procedures might work if I could upload a script to the server running the Postgres and have it run locally, however, I figured that would be rather annoying.

I have also considered wrapping the migration bundle inside another script that would allow for seeding operations on the server using regular SQL, but I figured that would make going up and down in versions more annoying.

Comment: You are going to need define large objects, are you referring to?: a) [Large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html) or b) [Binary types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am referring to Large Objects as in the stored JSON file. Objects that are placed there using lo_import and lo_export.

Comment: 1) Per [Large object pg_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77532240/pg-dump-behaviour-with-b-option/77534908#77534908) you should consider moving away from large objects. Especially as Postgres has [JSON(B)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) types. 2) Read the docs here [Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html) in particular [Server functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver As you can see, we are in fact trying to split our JSON file that is currently a large object up into multiple tables. To do this, I need to seed the data from it programmatically. I am trying to figure out how to do this as a step of dotnet ef migrations, but I need to read the data from the file in order to orient the seed data. Your response has not helped me in this, do you mind reading the question, again?

Comment: The  links I posted show how you pull data out of the system table [pg_largeobject](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-largeobject.html) where they are stored. That is the first step. Once you have the data pulled from the pg_largeobject table then you can do what it takes to move it the final database tables. How that is done is going to depend on the parameters for *...to be extracted into our database as a set of tables instead of JSON*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am aware that I can use lo_get to convert large objects to bytea and then insert those into a new table. My main problem is taking those bytea and loading/serializing them such that I can split them up into further tables as a part of a migration, such that I can extract specific parts and insert them into the multiple new tables I have. I want to be able in a migration to load those bytea into memory on my migrators end so that I can logic the exact data that is needed to be inserted. EF seems to only stick to SQL and I am trying to figure out extracting for seeding.

Comment: How do get the JSON out of the bytea now?

Comment: Since large objects are not accessible with SQL, you have to check if your .NET provider has a large object API. If yes, you will probably have to write custom code to read the large object. Or perhaps you can use SQL after all and use functions like `lo_open` and `lo_read`.